# Get data attribute from button in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

I use `Angularjs` for `pagination` loop button id=`remove_imslide` and then i want to get value of `data-img_id` from button to alert message in `Jquery` function on button click but it's not working.

In my view with Angularjs:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-app="angtable" ng-controller="imgslide">
    <table border="0">
        <tr dir-paginate="slide in slides|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage"
            current-page="currentPage">
            <td style="padding: 10px;border-color:lightgrey;">
                <table border="0" width="100%">                   
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                            <label for="timesheetinput1" style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">Title</label>
                                <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                    @{{slide.title}}
                                </div>
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="3" style="padding-left: 30px;width: 150px;">                           
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_imslide" name="remove_imslide" data-img_id="@{{slide.id}}"><i
                                class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                            <label for="timesheetinput1" style="color: blue;font-weight: bold;">Description</label>
                                <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                    @{{slide.detail}}
                                </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Jquery Script:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#remove_imslide').click( function(){
                alert(this.data('img_id'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: Try `alert($(this).data('img_id'));`

Comment: @linktoahref It's not working i think it seem to be jquery event not work in button loop in angularjs

Comment: Why don't you simply use the click event of the button and pass the id to it?:  ng-click='hadleClick(slide.id)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever mix AngularJS with jQuery. Please read this article carefully - ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). As you already said, your jQuery event is not binded on that AngularJS loop generated element. You should kick jQuery out of your application.

You can achieve this in the AnguarlJS way by using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). This would be the correct way to handle that kind of event - **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0b4L6418/)**:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button my-directive data-img_id="hello world">My button directive</button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function () {
          console.log(attrs.imgId);
        })
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: One more question how to pass it to control in modal??

Answer (score -1):

You have to write Js code in to onInit method of your component

```
onInit(){
   $('#remove_imslide').on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).data('img_id'));
   });
}
```